# Pine, why pivotlow always return the current price close?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to understand how *pivotlow* really works.

With this simple script, I display the value of *pivotlow* spanning from 5 bars in the past (5) and none in the future (0).

But if you run this script you will see that the value the function return change at every tick (it actually correspond to the value of the price close, see picture)...

```
//@version=4
study(title="TEST", overlay=true)

print(txt) =>
    label.new(bar_index, open, txt, yloc = yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

if(barstate.islast)
    print(tostring(pivotlow(close, 5, 0)))

plot(close)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not really call this function in a local scope.

Add `max_labels_count=500, max_bars_back=5000` to your `study()` call and you will see that it does not always return the current price.

It will return the current price if it is the lowest close of the last 5 bars. That is because you have 0 as your `rightbars` so it only looks at the previous bars.